# How do I enable https support in libcurl?

Tags: git, libcurl, homebrew

When I try to `$ brew update` I'm getting the error:

```
error: Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl while accessing https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
```

However, when I `$ curl --version`, I see:

```
curl 7.21.4 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8y zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.20
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

Unless I'm missing something, that looks good to me. Notice that `https` is listed in the protocols list.

`$ which curl` yields a suspicious response:

```
/usr/local/php5/bin/curl
```

Hmmmmm...maybe `brew` is using a different `curl` (like the one at `/usr/bin/curl`). Let's see:

`$ /usr/bin/curl --version`

```
curl 7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8y zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

Okay, it's obviously a different install of `curl`, but it's also listing `https` in the protocols list, and has the OpenSSL info there too.

BTW: I get the same error if I try to use an `https` URL with any `git` repo on my machine.

Questions:

1. <del>How can I determine the path to the `curl` that `brew` is using?</del>
2. How do I enable support for `https` in `libcurl`?

**UPDATE:** I was able to determine the path to `libcurl.4.dylib` that `git` (and `brew`) are using by following deltheil's method below. The path is:

```
/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.1.0)
```

So I tried this:

```
$ brew install curl --with-libssh2
```

Luckily curl is available at a non-SSL URI, so it actually did insstall. It didn't symlink into `/usr/local`, but that's fine with me (I think). So I did this:

```
$ cd /usr/lib
$ mv libcurl.4.dylib libcurl.4.dylib.bk
$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.30.0/lib/libcurl.4.dylib libcurl.4.dylib
$ brew update
```

But it's still throwing me this error:

```
error: Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl while accessing https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
```

So now the question exclusively becomes: How do I enable support for `https` in `libcurl`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I determine the path to the curl that brew is using?

Homebrew uses `/usr/bin/curl`, i.e the version that ships with Mac OS X, as you can see [here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/e9749ff2b0880a51877599a05ac58db6f12d3d8f/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb#L135).

That being said, and as you precise, your problem is probably related to the version of libcurl that is linked with `git` and used for `http://` and `https://`.

Perform a `which git` to determine which is the version you are being used (mine is installed under `/usr/local`).

Then scan the shared libraries used as follow:

```
$ otool -L /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-push | grep curl
/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
```

*Replace `/usr/local/` with the install directory that corresponds to your `git`.*

Since the libcurl version used by your `git` exec lacks of HTTPS support, this will tell you what is this version and where it is installed.

Comment: Thanks @deltheil, you got me halfway there. I've updated the question with current progress.

Comment: There's definitely something wrong somewhere since `git` is properly linked against system libcurl, which has support for https. That being said you should **never, ever** modify your system files under `/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib`, et al. I recommend you to run a `brew doctor` and check this [Github HTTPS cloning errors](https://help.github.com/articles/https-cloning-errors) page.

Comment: Alternatively you may want to properly install `git` via Homebrew with the `with-brewed-curl` option so that `git` uses `curl` from brew which depends on `darwinssl` for SSL support.

Comment: I ran `brew doctor` and it listed a bunch of files that were installed but not `brewed` or whatever...I deleted all of them except for some PHP5 config files that I know aren't any trouble, and it worked! Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Re-install curl and install it using the following commands (after unpacked):

```
$ ./configure --with-darwinssl    
$ make    
$ make test    
$ sudo make install
```

When you run the command "curl --version" you'll notice that the https protocol is now present under "protocols".

A helpful site if you run into curl problems: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on OSX. The issue were duplicate curl and curl.config files inside usr/local/bin that conflicted the same two files in usr/bin. I deleted the first set in the local/bin and Terminal worked after that.