# curl doesn't work from Pentaho Data Integration but it does in the terminal

Tags: curl, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I would like to execute the following curl from a transformation using the **Execute a process** step:

```
 curl -k --basic --user "user:pass" -d "input.string=\"{\"parameter\":3}\"" "https://localhost:5050/jobs?appName=test&classPath=MyTestClass&context=context_test"
```

But I get the following error:

Error output = curl: (1) Protocol "https not supported or disabled in libcurl

I execute the same command directly on the terminal and works fine.

I'm using the 6.0.1 version of PDI on a Centos 7 server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to do the same in my Windows machine and it worked fine (obviously I got a couldn't connect error as I have no endpoint similar to yours).

Anyway, I found another question that digs deeper about the same error on Linux ([How do I enable https support in libcurl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015282/how-do-i-enable-https-support-in-libcurl)). I think you have to discover which curl Pentaho is using as it can be different from your default installation.

Anyway, have you considered using HTTP Client step instead of using external process? I think it has performance/debug pros and you won't be tied to an external lib version/installation to make your job work.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right, seems that Pentaho is using a diferent curl. I wonder why, I thought that the **Execute a Process** step will directly send the command to the linux terminal but seems to not be in that way.

Comment: Glad it helped! Another thing that I learned that will be useful sometime in production for sure.

Comment: Any idea how one could get this to run curl or wget commands from pentaho? I'm getting an error that 'wget: command not found' when I try to run a script that works perfectly via terminal (Mac OS Sierra)

Answer (score 0):

For the Kettle to work, your request shall be POST with soap action header

curl -X POST --header 'SOAPAction;' --basic --user 'username:password'  'url'