# PHP cURL suddenly not working without any reason

Tags: php, curl

I am currently working on a project which makes an ajax call to my API on the same server. All went good and fine till a few hours ago when cURL **suddenly** stopped working **without any reason** and it's giving me following error

```
Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

But it doesn't make any sense because it worked earlier and the only thing I changed was something in the login-screen (only PHP) and the timezone on the server from default to "Europe/Berlin" with

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
[php.ini] date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin";
```

I've already restarted apache2, rebooted the server, checked the php.ini file and my phpinfo, it's all the same without any errors or changes, but curl just won't work. I tried to curl other hosts & localhost but nothing works. I also checked /var/mail/root, there aren't any errors.

Few information to my server

- Debian 8
- SSL certificate by Symantec
- full-root-access without any restrictions

That's the cURL-Code I am using

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($params));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

    session_write_close();
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    session_start();
```

Like I said it worked fine and without any problems for longer than 1 month. That's the weirdest thing I've ever seen. I hope somebody can help me.
If not, are there any good alternatives to curl? (POST-Requests)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595820/protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl

Comment: Esp. take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28220576/457268 Maybe the way your URL was build changed.

Comment: `Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl` it means the `libcurl` was installed without `https` supporting.  Please refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015282/how-do-i-enable-https-support-in-libcurl

Comment: It worked earlier.. so I don't get why it shouldn't work now? My URL did not changed. I didn't either changed libcurl.

Comment: What you expect to return back?

Comment: `without any reason` that your reason `https not supported or disabled in libcurl`

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić It depends on which function I call. Sometimes it's just "true", "done", a number etc..

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions, did you read my post? It worked 4 hours ago, I changed the timezone and then it stopped working.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7280074/4916265  and maybe show an example URL. This is very complex. And when something is not any more working then there is always a reason. That was my point. Also do you change the timezone back to check if it wll work again?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions, yes I tried to change it back, but it didn't worked either. I tried several URLs, not only mine. Nothing works, even google.com or other don't work, but in the past (like 4 hours ago) they worked.

Comment: Can you host a fresh virtual host with fresh apache and test. Problem is that there are so many places where something can be wrong.  You have to locate the bug in a away. How about testing a CURL via command line. And on and on...

Comment: With that, @iMostLiked, are you certain that your server has outside connectivity? Not sure if you're talking about a local server or a remote server (like a VPS).

Comment: I am on a VPS and my server has outside connectivity, I checked that. And like I said, it worked fine until I changed the timezone. Changing it back, doesn't fix that bug.

Comment: are you tr restart whole server?

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić, I finally solved it. Check my answer on this question.

Comment: @iMostLiked Thanks! Interesting problem realy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all for your help but I found the error.
The problem was the following:

`curl` didn't worked with https protocol, because there was a broken link/file in the libraries folder. If curl isn't working for you, check with `curl --version` if you get the following error:

```
curl: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by curl)
```

If yes, go to `/usr/local/lib` and delete both `libcurl` links/files. This solved the problem for me. After that just restart apache2 and it should work again.

**Note that this only solved the problem for me and it's not a global solving problem. So be aware of what you delete on your server. Always make a backup!**

Answer (score 2):

One thing what can made a problem is

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($params));`

Try to define like this:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`

Here is one setup what works great for me:

```
$default = array(
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => http_build_query($data),
            CURLOPT_POST            => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 10,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array('Accept: application/json')
        );

        $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
            $output=curl_exec($ch);     
        curl_close($ch);
```

But note this: `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` is in this example setup to accept JSON.

Also `http_build_query` can fix some parse problems inside your post data. Is not important to use but can help.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. It's still returning me `POST APIHandle.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: You have problem in file you visit via CURL not inside CURL. Look inside error.log

Comment: To follow up on why `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($params))` can be a problem, that option refers to a boolean field, not a numeric one.

Comment: It doesn't matter which file it is. If I try to get another file it returns `Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl`.

Comment: @iMostLiked Try with this `sudo apt-get install curl` :)

Comment: Try rreinstall curl, maby you have some issue in server configuration, that also happen.

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić, I think you are not going to believe me, but I tried thousand ways, including this, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Error `POST APIHandle.php 500 (Internal Server Error)` is internal error inside `APIHandle.php`, `Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl` is server configuration problem. Look inside apache, look all services is running or not. Also look inside `php.ini` is `curl` enabled

Comment: It's not a problem with my APIHandle.php, because when I try to curl something without my API (only test.php), it shows me `Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl`, so it has to be a problem with curl. When I try to curl over my API, it returns an internal server error, which is normal, because curl can't curl. Curl is enabled, phpinfo and php.ini are saying so.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that for some reason my server updated from PHP 7.3 to PHP 7.4. I actually downgraded to 7.3 because whoever compiled that copy of 7.4 botched compiling it to the point where anyone in their right mind would be less embarrassed to go on national TV without wearing pants. No server reboot necessary.

I caught the issue because I implemented detection via `function_exists()` for some important PHP functions after I encountered that absolutely abysmal copy of PHP.

So make sure if you're running multiple PHP versions that your server did not decide to blindly update to a newer and inferior (compiled) version.